# xcode stop a sprite from going off screen cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, screen, sprite, boundary

im using the below code but that doesnt seem to be stopping the sprite from going off screen even though the code builds. can anyone tell me how it needs to be changed so that when the sprite gets to the edge of the screen along the x coordinate it stops.

```
-(void)applyJoystick:(SneakyJoystick *)aJoystick toNode:(CCNode *)tempNode forTimeDelta:(float)deltaTime
{
CGPoint scaledVelocity = ccpMult(aJoystick.velocity, 1024.0f);
CGPoint newPosition = ccp(tempNode.position.x + scaledVelocity.x * deltaTime, tempNode.position.y);
CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
CGFloat spriteWidth = vikingSprite.contentSize.width;
CGFloat x = tempNode.position.x + scaledVelocity.x * deltaTime;
if (x < 0 + (spriteWidth/2)) {
    x = 0 + (spriteWidth/2);
} else if (x > screenSize.width - (spriteWidth/2)) {
    x = screenSize.width - (spriteWidth/2);

}
[tempNode setPosition:newPosition];
if (jumpButton.active == YES) {
    CCLOG(@"Jump button is pressed.");
}
if (attackButton.active == YES) {
    CCLOG(@"Attack button is pressed.");
}
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You never re-assign the changed variable x back to your vikingsprite after you modified it.

So you need to do something like:

```
if (x < 0 + (spriteWidth/2)) {
    x = 0 + (spriteWidth/2);
} else if (x > screenSize.width - (spriteWidth/2)) {
    x = screenSize.width - (spriteWidth/2);

}
CGPoint vikingPos = cpp(x, vikingsprite.position.y);
[vikingsprite setPosition:vikingPos];
```

My syntax could be wrong I don't write a lot of objective-c, but I use cocos2d-x which is the C++ version of cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

Set [edge as boundary](http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12).

```
 boundary.SetAsEdge(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
```

Don't forget to send Ray Wenderlich a beer.

Comment: im not using the box 2d engine with cocos 2d can i still use that bit of code

Comment: No you can't. But you should consider Box2D, reimplementing such code will probably lead you to potholes. You actually already encountered one ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your forgetting to reset it's position?

```
if (x < 0 + (spriteWidth/2)) {
x = 0 + (spriteWidth/2);
tempNode.position.x = x;
} else if (x > screenSize.width - (spriteWidth/2)) {
x = screenSize.width - (spriteWidth/2);
    tempNode.position.x = x;


}
```

Comment: sorry this failed it said Lvalue required as left operand of assignment.. any other suggestions?